# Pass index to jQuery from LINQ (VB)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having trouble with VB LINQ syntax. I have a web service that is returning JSON to jQuery and I need the index of the items but can't figure it out.

```
 Dim newsItems = From news In newsItems.Skip((page - 1) * 1).Take(10) _
        Select New With { _
           .Title = news.Name, _
           .Link = GetItemUrl(news) _
        }
```

In addition to the Title and Link, I'd also like to get the index of each item.  What would I add to this to make that happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload `Select` extension method that does what you want.

Try this:

```
Dim newsItems2 = _
    newsItems _
        .Skip((page - 1) * 1) _
        .Take(10) _
        .Select(Function (news, index) New With { _
           .Title = news.Name, _
           .Link = GetItemUrl(news), _
           .Index = index _
        })
```

I code in C# more so these days, so I hope I got the syntax right. It not it should be close.

Comment: Hilarious, no one answered my question so I finally figured it out. Came back here to post the answer and saw this. You're missing a closing parenthesis, but other than that, exactly what I came up with. Thanks!

Comment: @WillS - Thanks. I popped in the missing bracket. :-)